# OBS Studio snap does not show webcam or virtual camera

Tags: snap, webcam, dkms, obs-studio

I have installed the snap version of OBS Studio, and followed the instructions on this webpage: https://snapcraft.io/obs-studio

I want to use the virtual camera option to blur my background in other applications like Zoom/MS Teams etc.
(I also like the idea of doing more professional presentations with a welcome screen etc.)

The first time installing `v4l2loopback-dkms` resulted in an error:

```
dkms can't load "/var/lib/shim-signed/mok/.rnd" into rng
```

After removing it, and installing it again, it installed without issue.
`snap connections obs-studio` seems to show that the connections are fine.

```
Interface                 Plug                                 Slot                            Notes
alsa                      obs-studio:alsa                      :alsa                           manual
audio-playback            obs-studio:audio-playback            :audio-playback                 -
audio-record              obs-studio:audio-record              :audio-record                   -
avahi-control             obs-studio:avahi-control             :avahi-control                  manual
browser-support           obs-studio:browser-support           :browser-support                -
camera                    obs-studio:camera                    :camera                         -
content[gtk-3-themes]     obs-studio:gtk-3-themes              gtk-common-themes:gtk-3-themes  -
content[icon-themes]      obs-studio:icon-themes               gtk-common-themes:icon-themes   -
content[sound-themes]     obs-studio:sound-themes              gtk-common-themes:sound-themes  -
desktop                   obs-studio:desktop                   :desktop                        -
desktop-legacy            obs-studio:desktop-legacy            :desktop-legacy                 -
gsettings                 obs-studio:gsettings                 :gsettings                      -
home                      obs-studio:home                      :home                           -
jack1                     obs-studio:jack1                     :jack1                          manual
joystick                  obs-studio:joystick                  -                               -
kernel-module-observe     obs-studio:kernel-module-observe     :kernel-module-observe          manual
network                   obs-studio:network                   :network                        -
network-bind              obs-studio:network-bind              :network-bind                   -
opengl                    obs-studio:opengl                    :opengl                         -
password-manager-service  obs-studio:password-manager-service  -                               -
process-control           obs-studio:process-control           -                               -
pulseaudio                obs-studio:pulseaudio                :pulseaudio                     -
raw-usb                   obs-studio:raw-usb                   -                               -
removable-media           obs-studio:removable-media           -                               -
screen-inhibit-control    obs-studio:screen-inhibit-control    :screen-inhibit-control         -
screencast-legacy         obs-studio:screencast-legacy         -                               -
system-observe            obs-studio:system-observe            -                               -
unity7                    obs-studio:unity7                    :unity7                         -
upower-observe            obs-studio:upower-observe            :upower-observe                 -
wayland                   obs-studio:wayland                   :wayland                        -
x11                       obs-studio:x11                       :x11                            -
```

OBS Studio starts just fine, however I see no webcam as a source, nor the option to use the virtual camera in the `tools` menu.

When I start OBS Studio in the terminal I do get two errors:

```
info: [Move Transition] loaded version 2.4.3
error: os_dlopen(libnvidia-fbc.so.1->libnvidia-fbc.so.1): libnvidia-fbc.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

error: Unable to load NvFBC library
warning: Failed to initialize module 'nvfbc.so'
warning: Failed to load 'en-US' text for module: 'obs-audio-pan-filter.so'
info: [obs-audio-pan-filter] plugin loaded successfully (version 0.1.0)
info: [obs-browser]: Version 2.14.3
info: [obs-browser]: CEF Version 87.1.14+ga29e9a3+chromium-87.0.4280.141
error: os_dlopen(libnvidia-encode.so.1->libnvidia-encode.so.1): libnvidia-encode.so.1: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

info: FFMPEG VAAPI supported
warning: Failed to load 'en-US' text for module: 'obs-gphoto.so'
info: obs-gstreamer build: 9ed970d
```

No clue if that has something to do with it.

Any ideas on how to fix this are greatly appreciated, because I am out of ideas. :)

---UPDATE---

I just installed the deb package version and it *does* pick up both the webcam and the virtual camera output.

Comment: You might consider asking perusing https://github.com/snapcrafters/obs-studio/issues to see if any of those issues are relevant. You might also consider asking your question there if you can't get help here.